# Interesting visual bug with bootstrap form inputs

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I am using bootstrap forms. In a form group I have some check boxes. When I hover my mouse over the first one, it highlights the first one as expected. When I hover over the second one, it highlights the **second** one **and** the **first** one. When I hover over the third one, it highlights the **third** one **and** the **first** one. And so on... I'm wondering if this is a known bug with bootstrap? I'm using nodeJS with pug on express server. Her is my code:

```
.form-group.centerCheckboxes
    label Local Center Statistics
        .form-check
            label.form-check-label
                input#tutorRequestFrequency.form-check-input(type='checkbox' value='tutorRequestFrequency')
                |  Tutor request frequency
        .form-check
            label.form-check-label
                input#totalWorkingHours.form-check-input(type='checkbox' value='totalWorkingHours')
                |  Total working hours
        .form-check
            label.form-check-label
                input#totalHoursTutored.form-check-input(type='checkbox' value='totalHoursTutored')
                |  Total hours tutored
        .form-check
            label.form-check-label
                input#totalWeightPulled.form-check-input(type='checkbox' value='totalWeightPulled')
                |  Tutors "weight pulled" ratios
```

perhaps I am using bootstrap classes wrong? This is all within a grid system but I've triple checked the grid to make sure all the numbers rows and columns were used properly. Has anybody ever heard of this problem or know why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It's because I was using the `label` tag incorrectly. when I hovered over anything within the `.form-group` it was also hovering over the `label` which was automatically being applied to the first checkbox in the list.

To solve this, instead of using `label` I instead used `div` then put the text that was originally inside the `label`  inside the `div`.